# Kotlin resolve function call vararg ambiguity

Tags: kotlin

In java, you can do:

```
Method m = XposedHelpers.findMethodBestMatch(WebView.class, "getWebViewClient");
```

However, if you convert this method to kotlin, you get:

```
val m = XposedHelpers.findMethodBestMatch(WebView::class.java, "getWebViewClient")
```

This will give an error: [image]

To my understanding, java will simply use one of the two functions and its not immediately clear which one it will call.

How do I choose to use either one of these functions in kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may pass an empty array explicitly, e.g.

```
XposedHelpers.findMethodBestMatch(WebView::class.java, "getWebViewClient", *emptyArray<Any>())
```

or

```
XposedHelpers.findMethodBestMatch(WebView::class.java, "getWebViewClient", *emptyArray<Class<*>>())
```

Comment: Using a spread operator with an empty array is a good way to explicitely define the parameter type, thank you!